# What is a SOAP interface?

Tags: web-services, soap

for a short time I'm getting into Web Services and today I came across this term "SOAP Interface". I can know intuitively what can it mean but it would be better if someone with knowledge enough could make it clearer.

I think it's the interface of a SOAP service. You implement a SOAP service and its input and output point is what we call interface. Am I right?

I read the term on the sentence of a manual: "*The OCSP Solution use following SOAP Interfaces:*"

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Comment: Your hunch seems spot on to me, and I work with SOAP interfaces on a daily basis.  Do you have any other questions?

Comment: At the moment that's all, thanks :) I was afraid of misunderstanding it or missing something. Have a good weekend

Comment: You might also see the term `REST interface` and the concept is the same.  Cheers.